# Rails Want to Display Object#Show inside a modal without loading application template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-modal

Instead of showing a table in my index page with links to each object's show path, I want to have each object as a bootstrap modal where it will render the show view inside the modal. When I click on the modal, it displays the entire application.html.erb template inside the modal instead of the show view of the object. Is there a way to just display the object's show view, while still staying on the index page and not yielding the entire application template.

index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Buildings</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>County</th>
       ...
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @buildings.each do |building| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', building %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_building_path(building) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', building, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
<div class="text-center">
  <%= link_to "#{building.development_name}", building, class: 'btn btn-primary', data: {toggle:'modal', target: '#myModal'} %>
</div>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<div class="modal inmodal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <i class="fa fa-laptop modal-icon"></i>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><%= building.development_name %></h4>
        <small class="font-bold">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...  
        <div class="form-group"><label>Sample Input</label> <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <% end %>
```

buildings_controller.rb

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_building, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /buildings
  # GET /buildings.json
  def index
    @buildings = Building.where(user_id: current_user)
  end

  # GET /buildings/1
  # GET /buildings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /buildings/new
  def new
    @building = Building.new
  end

  # GET /buildings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /buildings
  # POST /buildings.json
  def create
    @building = Building.new(building_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @building.save
        session[:building_id] = @building.id
        redirect_to listing_wizards_path
        format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'Building was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @building }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @building.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /buildings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /buildings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @building.update(building_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'Building was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @building }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @building.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /buildings/1
  # DELETE /buildings/1.json
  def destroy
    @building.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to buildings_url, notice: 'Building was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_building
      @building = Building.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def building_params
      params.require(:building).permit(:list_type, :county, :area, :city, :folio, :street, :compass_point, :street_name, :state, :zip, :zip4, :unit, :legal, :zoning, :geographical, :municip_code, :township, :section, :subdivision, :parcel, :map_coordinates, :elementary_school, :middle_school, :senior_high_school, :subdivision_name, :development_name, :model_name_in_mls, :user_id, additional_room_ids: [], amenity_ids: [], approval_ids: [], construction_ids: [], cooling_description_ids: [], design_ids: [], dining_area_ids: [], equipment_ids: [], exterior_feature_ids: [], floor_ids: [], heat_ids: [],  interior_feature_ids: [], leasing_term_ids: [], lot_description_ids: [], misc_ids: [], parking_restriction_ids: [], pet_restriction_ids: [], pool_description_ids: [], rental_dep_incl_ids: [], rental_pay_inc_ids: [], rental_restriction_ids: [], security_ids: [], showing_instruction_ids: [], water_access_ids: [], waterfront_desc_ids: [], window_treatment_ids: [])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [the `layout` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option) when rendering your show method

> You can also tell Rails to render with no layout at all:
>
> ```
> render layout: false
> ```

If you'd like to still render the layout if they type the show url into the browser you can do

```
render layout: !request.xhr?
```

Just stick that in your `show` action and rails will still render the show view and then you can take the response in your Ajax call and put it into your modal.

Comment: thanks, it did work. It just shows the show.html.erb information inside the modal. A follow up question if I may, how can I style that info? It currently will only display the plain show action, if i add any divs etc it will just show the modal and not the show action info.